# How do I remove the new Windows 11 File Explorer toolbar

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I recently installed Windows 11 and there is a horrible new toolbar in Windows Explorer that mostly just duplicates functions from the toolbar directly above it. Any idea how I can remove the toolbar I highlighted in the screenshot?
[image: The new toolbar highlighted]

My Windows Information:

- Edition   Windows 11 Pro
- Version   23H2
- Installed on  ‎11/‎29/‎2023
- OS build  22631.2715
- Experience    Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22677.1000.0

Comment: Is Windows 11 fully updated ?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, Windows is fully updated

Comment: @Ramhound I added my specific Windows information. What other details would be helpful? I thought the problem is stated clearly, I want to remove the toolbar highlighted in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The toolbar was a (poorly designed) beta feature. I was able to remove it by leaving the Windows Insider Program.